# Gamepad Button Mapping

Tags: macbook-pro

For some reason, my gamepad has wrong mappings, and I need a software to remap the joystick. Is there any free tool for that? Or a workaround maybe?

Comment: Which OS, gamepad? What have you already tried? Please provide more information so we can help further.

Comment: big sur, joypad brand is axcess